# How should I install tile on plywood?

Tags: tile

I am installing tile directly to plywood. It is for a bar, foot rest area approximately 7 inches wide. what is thr easiest, cheapest way to accomplish. Wont be wet, wont be walked on, more for looks than anything

Comment: Did you try Liquid Nails? Or any relatable alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Given that it won't be walked on, I'd say spread a very thin layer of thinset, give it 24 hours to set, then just do a regular tile job with thinset and tiles followed by grout. The hardest part of this job will be cutting the rearmost row of tiles so your bullnose is even with the edge.

Comment: I would go this way for the fact that people will be pushing off the area with their feet.  Mastic is really meant for areas that won't be touched.

Answer (score 0):

Thinset and grout is not cheap and easy enough for you?

Construction adhesive (giant tube-o-glue) to attach it and caulk for "grout" I suppose. I've had some success with a "short of ripping up the whole floor and doing it over right" repair with construction adhesive to reattach a loose tile on a badly done floor, so it might work well enough.

"Mastic" would be the other logical product, though I tend only to think of it with vinyl tiles - but ceramics are a claimed application for many products. Not endorsing nor associated - I haven't used any type of mastic in years.

[image: Image from laticrete - not endorsing nor associated]